# Image is empty of has incorrect depth error in KnnMatcher OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, sift

so I wrote some code a while ago that runs the SIFT `detectAndCompute()` function on a black and white version of my image called `gray`. My code had been running fine with the images I was working with but has started failing recently. I get this error whenever I run my code:

> error: (-5) image is empty or has incorrect depth (!=CV_8U) in function cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT_Impl::detectAndCompute

I know the problem occurs whenever I have the wrong image depth or an empty image but neither of those seem to be the case with my code. I print out the image name so I know that the file is being reached. I was wondering if anyone knows possible reasons why my code could be failing.

This is the code where I try to run `detectAndCompute` on the image after I convert it to grayscale.

```
#Class constructor -  basically an initializer
def __init__(self, image, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.image = image
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
    (self.kps, self.features) = sift.detectAndCompute(gray,None)
    self.kps = np.float32([kp.pt for kp in self.kps])
```

and this is the code where I read in the image files from a folder.

```
#import spam grid images from folder
images = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob("SpAMImages/*")]
#obtain SpAM reference image names
file_names= [os.path.basename(file).split(".")[0] for file in             
glob.glob("SpAMImages/*")]

for image, file_name in zip(images, file_names):
    print(file_name)
```

Comment: It seems you should convert the image to dtype `CV_8U` maybe?

Comment: @kevinkayaks OP uses `cv2.imread` to load the images, so that would give `CV_8U` arrays (or rather `numpy.uint8`, since we're in Python) -- 3 channel ones in fact, since the second parameter is left at default value. What's more likely is that `image is None` due to that specific `imread` failing (perhaps trying to read something other than an image, since OP grabs everything with the `glob`).

Comment: Is is possible that the image is corrupted? Maybe it's not even an image but something else (it says spam images, and it's not so unusual that ... um how to call those creatures politely ... ***** rename an executable as an image with the hope that naive people click on it and run a program that compromises their machine).

Comment: @DanMašek I looked at my code some more and indeed no image is being passed into `detectAndCompute`. The code I use to crop an image before running `detectAndCompute` seems to be going out of bounds so no image is produced thus why it appears as none when `detectAndCompute` is run. Thanks for all your help.